# Setting the name of an object in Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I've got a React app that holds a survey and I'm trying to add results to database using Firebase. Basically I want each result set from a user taking the survey stored. I've created a variable that is the current date/time for when the survey is complete. So my plan was to have it look like for example 10/6/2020: result_set, but I'm getting an issue trying to set that, I think its just a basic syntax issue but I'm not entirely sure.

```
var moment = require('moment');
var now = moment().format();

database.ref('users/results').update({
   this.now: results_set
});
```

It won't allow me to use 'this.now' but using 'now' just sets it to the string 'now' basically, is there a way to set it to a variable? Like I said it's probably just incorrect syntax but I'm stuck on it, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
database.ref('users/results').update({
   [this.now]: results_set
});
```

By surrounding the variable in square brackets, the value of that variable ends up becoming the property name.